# Running OLS Regression Between columns of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I want to define a function that runs OLS model between each columns of dataframe with the last column. I have for example a dataframe with 13 columns so I've to run OLS regression 12 times and it's too much to write.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import linear_model


DF = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
print(DF)

# Regression Model
for columns in DF:
    reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(DF[['INCOME']], DF.x)

reg1 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg1.fit(DF[['INCOME']], DF.FOOD)

reg2 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg2.fit(DF[['INCOME']], DF.SMOKING)

.
.
.
reg11 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg11.fit(DF[['INCOME']], DF.HOTEL)

reg12 = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg12.fit(DF[['INCOME']], DF.OTHERS)

#Beta Coefficeints

B1 = reg1.coef_
B2 = reg2.coef_
   .
B10 = reg10.coef_
B11 = reg11.coef_
B12 = reg12.coef_

print(B1)
print(B2)
 .`
print(B10)
print(B11)
print(B12)
```

I just want to make it shorter

Comment: Loop over all columns in `Df.columns` (except INCOME) and do the model fitting inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the column and store results in a dictionary, namely:

```py
from sklearn import linear_model

dict = {}

for i in df.columns:
    reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
    reg.fit(df[['INCOME']], df[i])
    dict[i] = reg.coef_
    print(dict[i])
```

Comment: thanks it works
but I want my regression coefficient as variable because they are necessary for equation system